# Cannot install xml.etree.elementtree in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, xml.etree

```
  Using cached pycopy-xml.etree.ElementTree-0.1.2.tar.gz (1.9 kB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'F:\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ncg_nv94'
         cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Formatting the error will help us read it. Surround it in triple backticks (```)

Comment: Please show us what are you doing to get this error, either clicking something on the IDE or a terminal command you run...

Comment: i am trying to install pycopy-xml.etree.elementtree in pycharm.. and i m not able to install it

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to install py-xml: the ElementTree API is part of the standard library of Python

[here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)

In fact, py-xml is an old and probably obsolete package whose installation script appears to be only compatible with Python 2. One more reason why you don't need to install it!
If you would have just put the import statement in your code it would have worked without any issue in that regard.